# how to replace images in image folder in vb

Tags: vb.net, image, replace

i have made image loading small application in `vb.net.`

i want to replace images in folder. but i cannot replace because its says image is using another application. my idea is i want to make an application like window will show images keep changing.

**for EX:-** *01.jpg* i will replace with same name difference image.
only problem when i am going to replace image its give **error msg** `"cannot replace 01.jpg image using another application"`.

i dont want to copy and rename it from codes. i just want to copy my self and past it in windows explorer. but while showing the image from my application its need to update which i replaced image. problem is when i am replacing my self manually its give msg

plz help me how to fix this issue.

**my code:**

```
PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\1.jpg")
```

Comment: Close the application that uses the file...

Comment: hi thanks for quick answer. but i dont want to close application.that application is what i made vb.net application.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN said

`The file remains locked until the Image is disposed`

Set nothing to your pictbox first before rename your pic file

```
PictureBox1.Image = nothing
```

If you still want rename picture that shown in the picture box, you may do this

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\1.jpg","C:\Temp.jpg") '--> your pict shown always named temp.jpg

 PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Temp.jpg")

 My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile("C:\1.jpg", "C:\whatever.jpg")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i dont want to copy and rename it from codes. i just want to copy my self and past it in windows explorer. but while showing the image from my application its need to update which i replaced image. problem is when i am replacing my self manually its give msg.

Comment: @3dnipuna .. it wont be happened .. as long as your picbox display the pic's contain